# jenkins plugin version to jenkins version mapping?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When I go to my "manage plugins" section of Jenkins 1.620, I see this message on many "available" plugins:

> Warning: This plugin is built for Jenkins 1.625.3 or newer. It may or may not work in your Jenkins.

So I think there is no connection between the installed Jenkins version and the plugin versions available because It shows plugins for a higher version of Jenkins.

Is there a way to figure out which particular plugin version hpi file I need to download for my jenkins version? Is there such a mapping available?

I tried looking for it in the git source for the plugin (Eg: ws-cleanup-plugin) but it has no readme..